# Job spooled to Canon MP140 printer, but nothing printed

Tags: printing, windows-xp, canon

I am trying to print documents from my Ubuntu 10.0.4 LTS machine to my Windows XP machine. I have a Canon MP140 printer connected to my Windows XP machine.

I followed the instructions given [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsXPPrinter), and I managed to find and install the printer and printer driver successfully. After the printer installation, I try to print a test page (using the printer GUI), my Ubuntu machine informs me that the print job is being spooled to the printer - but nothing gets printed to the printer.

When I looked in `/var/log/cups`, I saw this entry in `error.log`:

```
Unable to remove temporary file "/var/spool/cups/tmp/.hplip" - Is a directory
```

and in `access.log`, there was this line entry:

```
localhost - - [05/Feb/2012:11:22:45 +0000] "POST /printers/Canon-MP140 HTTP/1.1" 200 35135 Print-Job successful-ok
```

So it seems (to me at least), that everything is working normally (apart from the failure to delete the tmp file).

Does anyone know why my documents are not being printed? (Yes, the printer is switched on.)

I installed the MP140 drivers using the instructions I found here: [MP40 driver installation](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1818114)